# Angular-cli (7.3.8), production environment, how to write compiled runtime.js directly into HTML instead of js reference?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, webpack-4

"@angular/cli": "~7.3.8", angular7.2, are the latest version default settings.

The runtime.js file generated after packaging is too small, I want to write it directly into the html file, saving one resource request.

Since angular-cli cannot directly configure the webpack configuration, after reviewing the information: I decided to use "ngx-build-plus", additionally wrote a webpack configuration reference, and then used the plugin: "InlineManifestWebpackPlugin"

package.json：

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod --extraWebpackConfig"
  },
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.12.4",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "~7.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "ng-lazyload-image": "^5.1.2",
    "ngx-build-plus": "^7.8.1",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^7.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.2",
    "html-webpack-inline-source-plugin": "0.0.10",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.5",
    "inline-manifest-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack-cdn-plugin": "^3.0.0"
  }
```

angular.json

```
....
"architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "ngx-build-plus:build",
      ....
```

webpack.extra.js

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const InlineManifestWebpackPlugin = require('inline-manifest-webpack-plugin')
module.exports = {
  plugins:[
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),
    new InlineManifestWebpackPlugin()
  ]
}
```

But the result is Packing error, the possible reason is that angular-cli uses webpack4.0+, but "html-webpack-plugin" is version 3.2. But even if I use the html-webpack-plugin@next version, I still get an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'tapAsync' of undefined.
```

Am I having something wrong? Or is there a better way to write "runtime.js" into HTML instead of generating a reference?

0.o

Thank~

Comment: Did you try to split out the runtime code? https://www.npmjs.com/package/inline-manifest-webpack-plugin

Comment: yes of course，I mentioned it above, but it failed.